# Does Mifare RFID Reader support NFC?

Tags: java-me, symbian, nfc, rfid

Does Mifare [RFID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio-frequency_identification) Reader(13.56 MHz) support [NFC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Near_Field_Communication)?I want to develop an application using Nokia  mobile. Is it possible to formatting the Mifare  RFID cards using NFC enabled mobile?

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about the USB RFID reader? It depends, there are RFID readers with and without the NFC support... Which Nokia phones do you plan to use to communicate with RFID reader and in which mode? If this is a Symbian C7 or other model I suggest to use the C++ API for native Symbian and/or Qt.

Answer (score 0):

It's very likely that your Mifare RFID 13.56 reader supports NFC. 13.56 is the high frequency range of RFID that NFC covers. There are several models of NFC readers that are guaranteed to work; there are different forms factors as well as interfaces ([LCD](http://www.buynfctags.com/acr122l-nfc-reader-with-lcd/), [portable](http://www.buynfctags.com/acr122t-nfc-portable-reader-and-writer/); [serial](http://www.buynfctags.com/serial-nfc-development-kit/), [USB](http://www.buynfctags.com/nfc-development-kit/), ...) to choose from. You will also need [software](http://www.buynfctags.com/categories/NFC-Kits/) for your reader. Your Nokia phone may be able to read/write the NFC tags... it all depends on which model you have.